# Getting function NOT to run on import

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have tried EVERY " if **name**=='**main**' " suggestion and it still fails (or maybe I'm doing it wrong or not understanding it).  I am also Not trying to run things from a command line.  While testing things out in Pycharm, I am trying to get the main file to pop-up with a gui and then when I click on the button, trying to get the first window to go away and the second file/gui to pop up in its place.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

## this is the main one I am trying to start with but opens up with the second gui first

```
from tkinter import *
from tryingstuff import EmdMain



class App:

    def __init__(self, master):

        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()
        #firebutton
        self.fphoto = PhotoImage(file="../icon/fireorig.png")
        self.fbutton = Button(frame, image=self.fphoto)
        self.fbutton.config( height=228, width=200)
        self.fbutton.pack(side=LEFT)
        #emsbutton
        self.mphoto = PhotoImage(file="../icon/ems.png") 
        self.emsButton = Button(frame, image=self.mphoto, command=EmdMain)
        self.emsButton.config( height=224, width=197)
        self.emsButton.pack(side=RIGHT)

root = Tk()
root.title("ProQA Card set")
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

## This is the second file

```
from tkinter import *

def EmdMain():

    frame = Frame()
    frame.pack()

    abdominalPnB = Button(frame, text="01_Abdominal Pain")
    abdominalPnB.config(anchor="w", width=20, height=1)
    abdominalPnB.grid(row=0, column=0)



root = Tk()
app = EmdMain()
root.mainloop()

if __name__=='__main__':
    EmdMain()
```

Comment: P.s : I have also tried labeling EmdMain as class and still nothing

Comment: Put the whole `root = Tk(); app = EmdMain(); root.mainloop()` block in the second file under the `if __name__ == "__main__"` guard.

Comment: I love you, thank you SOOOO much, that worked!